# Contour Map NOT Circular in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, contour

I'm trying get a basic circular temperature contour graph in MATLAB.

Instead, I'm getting a straight line and doesn't resemble at all to

MATLAB's examples for contour maps. I want 4 circular zones

representing 90 degrees, 80 degrees, 70 degrees, and 60 degrees.

Here is my code:

```
long = [0 1 2 3; 4 5 6 7; 8 9 10 11; 12 13 14 15];
lat = [15 16 17 18; 19 20 21 22; 23 24 25 26; 27 28 29 30];
temp = [98 95 94 92; 85 82 81 80; 72 75 74 71; 65 62 61 69];
figure; 
contour(long,lat,temp,4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've only provided a line of data and not a matrix. You need to provide a temperature for each pair of `long` and `lat`.   So if `long` and `lat` are both 1x15 then `temp` should be 15x15.

For example:

```
x = 1:3
y = 1:3
z = [1 2 1; 2 3 2; 1 2 1];

contour(x,y,z);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help -- the missing piece!